# Number of hyperconjugating structures due to a C=N system

Tags: organic-chemistry

> How many hyperconjugating strutures are there for the following compound?
>
> [image]

I thought the answer to be 8 (as there are eight alpha hydrogens) but the correct answer given is zero. Why isn't the answer eight here, as expected from a $\ce{C=C}$ alkene? Does the explanation invoke the very definition of hyperconjugation?

Comment: this question came in my test today. Answer given is 8

Comment: a chemistry faculty told me it is  0.(that too an experienced one)